# MagSafe 1 or 2 for MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, magsafe

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro and need to know if I should be using a MagSafe 1 or 2 charger. I've searched around with Google but so far I've found conflicting information.

I recently ordered an 85W MagSafe 2 (T-style) car charger and while the green light comes on showing power coming in, the menubar battery doesn't show the lighting bolt in the UI.

Need to know if it is just defective or if I'm buying the wrong charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/HT201700), you're using the right adapter (the MagSafe 2 connector). According to this page, the MBPs that you should use are:

> **85W MagSafe power adapter with MagSafe 2 style connector**
>
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inch, Mid 2015)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
> - Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)

and

> **60W MagSafe power adapter with MagSafe 2 style connector**
>
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012)

If your MBP still isn't charging, try the SMC reset (as mentioned by @LangLangC) and/or bring it into an Apple store to confirm whether the problem is with your laptop. Another thing to try is finding a friend/co-worker that has a MagSafe 2 adapter to confirm whether your power charger is working.

Answer (score 1):

[Those two styles for the glorious magsafes are physically different. If it fits without an adapter you have the right prong for your machine.](https://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MD592LL/A/whats-the-difference-between-magsafe-and-magsafe-2/QJ77K4JP2C9CFAT74)
An overview for which Apple (don't call it)laptop mobile devices need which can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700).

The menubar not reflecting what the charger is telling you may be caused by something else. 
You indicated that your charger is *declared* as having the right power rating. Since it is apparently not an Apple product giving you problems, you might want to check if it really delivers the amount of power adversed.

Trying an SMC reset and making sure the connector for the charger on the MBP is clean would be the next steps. Defective chargers cannot be ruled out entirely. Since it's new, go let it be checked out.